# AngularJS ui modal not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building application on AngularJS and I'm using ui-modal, but instead of creating separete views for edit and create (which are identical) i want two instances of modal operating on the same view. This is what I did

I have one main controller which has functions for create and edit, both of them opens their own instance of modal :

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'app.projects' )

    .controller('ProjectsController', ProjectsController ); 

    ProjectsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modal'];

    function ProjectsController( $scope, $modal ) 
    {

        $scope.edit = function( projectId ) 
          {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open(
            {
              templateUrl: 'modules/projects/view/modal/project.html',
              controller: 'EditProjectModalInstController',
              size: 'lg',
              resolve: {
                projectId: function(){
                    return projectId;
                }
              }
            });
          };

        $scope.create = function() 
          {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open(
            {
              templateUrl: 'modules/projects/view/modal/project.html',
              controller: 'CreateProjectModalInstController',
              size: 'lg',
            });
          };
    };
})();
```

Here are those modal instances controllers:
**EditProjectModalInstanceController**

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'app.projects' )

    .controller( 'EditProjectModalInstController', EditProjectModalInstController );

    EditProjectModalInstController.$inject = ['ProjectsService', '$scope', '$modalInstance', 'projectId'];

    function EditProjectModalInstController(projectsService, $scope, $modalInstance, projectId) 
    {
        $scope.project = function(){return projectsService.project;};

        $scope.statuses = [
            {name: 'Active', value: 0},
            {name: 'Finished', value: 1}
        ];

        $scope.cancel = function () {};

        $scope.save = function(){}; 
    };


})();
```

and here is **CreateProjectModalInstanceController.js**

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';

    angular.module( 'app.projects' )

    .controller( 'CreateProjectModalInstController', CreateProjectModalInstController );

    CreateProjectModalInstController.$inject = ['ProjectsService', '$scope', '$modalInstance'];

    function CreateProjectModalInstController( projectsService, $scope, $modalInstance ) 
    {
        $scope.project = function(){return {};};

        $scope.statuses = [
            {name: 'Active', value: 0},
            {name: 'Finished', value: 1}
        ];

        $scope.cancel = function(){};

        $scope.save = function(){};
    };
})();
```

So each instance controller has same function, is just that they should do different things depends on action(edit or create).

And here is the actual template:
**project.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" ng-model="project().name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="control-label col-xs-2">Status</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="project().status">
                    <option ng-repeat="status in statuses" value="{{status.value}}">{{status.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button ng-click="save()"> Save </button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And finally the issue, my problem here is that edit functionality is working fine, but when the create modal is opened, i can not edit field. I'm felling that I'm doing something wrong here, in sense of design principals and I would really appreciate if someone with more experience could point out correct way of doing this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having with not being able to edit a create form is because your `$scope.project` function is returning a new object every time it is called. This means almost any action you take will overwrite anything saved in that object. To remedy this just assign the empty object to `$scope.project` instead of using a function:

```
$scope.project = {};
```

And then reference in the template like so:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" ng-model="project.name">
```

The only reason it works for editing is because the function returns the same object from the `projectsService` instead of creating a new one each time.

Once you have that working you can begin refactoring by DRYing up your controllers.  There are several ways to approach this but I would just have different resolve options for create and edit; create would have a `null` project ID and edit would have the editing project ID.

Create:

```
$scope.create = function() {
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'modules/projects/view/modal/project.html',
     controller: 'ProjectFormModalInstController',
     size: 'lg',
     resolve: {
        projectId: null
     }
   });
};
```

Edit:

```
$scope.edit = function() {
   var modalInstance = $modal.open({
     templateUrl: 'modules/projects/view/modal/project.html',
     controller: 'ProjectFormModalInstController',
     size: 'lg',
     resolve: {
        projectId: projectId
     }
   });
};
```

This way you can use the same controller (I named it `ProjectFormModalInstController` but you can choose your own generic name) and the controller or the service can initialize a new project if the ID does not exist or return the project if an id is present.

```
function ProjectFormModalInstController( projectsService, $scope, $modalInstance, projectId ) {

  if ( projectId === null ) {
    $scope.project = {};
  } else {
    $scope.project = projectsService.project;
  }

  // ...some controller code

  $scope.save = function(){
     if ( project.id === null ) {
        // create project
     } else {
        // update project
     }
  };
};
```